# 'RCTConvert+AIRMap.h file not found error in React Native when trying to use Google Maps on iOS

Tags: react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

I am trying to integrate Google Maps into my React Native iOS application. I followed the steps outlined in the documentation and installed the react-native-maps library. However, when I try to build my project in Xcode, I found many solutions but no one is working for me and I get the following error:

'RCTConvert+AIRMap.h' file not found
I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue, but the error persists:

I checked that the react-native-maps library is installed correctly and I have linked it using react-native link react-native-maps.

I tried to clean the build folder and rebuild the project.

I have tried to manually add the RCTConvert+AIRMap.h file to my project, but it still gives me the same error.

I have checked that my Xcode project's search paths are set correctly and $(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-maps/ios/AirMaps is added to the header search paths.

I have also tried to delete the Podfile.lock file, and reinstall the Podfile by running pod install.

Despite all these efforts, I am still getting the same error. Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

[image]